# User 'npm_***' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

On Azure Pipelines I would like to consume a feed in my organization.
What I have done so far:

- Deactivate "Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines" in projects pipeline settings
- Added Project Build Service and Project Collection Build Service with Contributor Role to permissions of specific feed

I'm using npmAuthenticate task:

```
      - task: npmAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          workingFile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.npmrc
        displayName: 'NPM Authenticate'
        condition: ne(variables.cacheRestored, 'true')

      - script: |
          npm ci
        displayName: 'NPM ci'
        condition: ne(variables.cacheRestored, 'true')
```

npm ci gives following error:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET <package>.tgz - User 'npm_***' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'.
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

Why is named user named npm_*** ? I found several issues where user is named by id e.g. 826354b7-***. This part confuses me.

Comment: Hi, just to confirm, after you added Contributor Role to Build Service account in the feed permission setting and change the projects pipeline settings, did the error disappear?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help :-( Error is still present

Answer (score 0):

> Why is named user named npm_*** ? I found several issues where user is named by id e.g. 826354b7-***. This part confuses me.

I can reproduce the same error in my pipeline. Perhaps for privacy reasons, the username appears in the logs as "npm_***".

[image]

By the way, I also tested with a NuGet restore task. In the task, I tried to restore a NuGet package from the same artifact feed and this time, I got the error message with user ID.

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User '96fsxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'.
```

After I added Contributor Role to Project Build Service account in the feed permission setting, the errors in the NPM task and the NuGet restore task are gone.